# Чем отличается define() от const?

Tags: php

Объясните пожалуйста чем отличается строка

```
    const CONFIG = 'includes/db_config.php';
```

от строки

```
    define('CONFIG','includes/db_config.php');
```

Благодарю Вас!

Comment: Если знаешь английский, то почитай на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193704/6104996). Мне пока лень писать)

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8477/sozdanie-konstant-v-php-cherez-const-i-define.html). Всё описано в примерах для разных версий PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До php5.6 const нельзя указать переменную, функцию или какое то выражение, только скалярные величины.

```
const FOO = 'val';       // нет ошибок
const FOO = $var;        // Parse error
const FOO = home_url();  // Parse error
const FOO = 5 + 10;      // Parse error
const FOO = 'foo'.'bar'; // Parse error

define('FOO', 'val');         // нет ошибок
define('FOO', $var );         // нет ошибок
define('FOO', home_url() );   // нет ошибок
define('FOO', 5 + 10 );       // нет ошибок
define('FOO', 'foo'.'bar' );  // нет ошибок
```

После 5.6 - можно.

Так же после 5.6 const может хранить массивы, define только после 7.0

В остальном:

Const должны быть объявлены в верхней области.
Const всегда регистрозависима