# В каком же формате лучше хранить конфигурацию сайта: php, json или в другом

Tags: php, json

Насколько вижу на англоязычном SO ответы на данный вопрос расходятся: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809241/php-application-config-file-stored-as-ini-php-sql-cached-php-class-json-php) например пишут что

> The best thing you can do is the simplest thing that could possibly
>   work (php variables) and wrap it up in a class

А по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137211/how-to-set-save-the-variable-in-a-php-file добавляют, что перезаписывать переменные в php-файле конфигурации можно с помощью `var_export`

Но по той же второй ссылке в первом комменте к вопросу *@Quentin* призывает не использовать файл в формате php, а лучше `"ini, JSON, XML, etc"` (меня интересует только хранение в файле, а не в базе данных). А *@symcbean* обьясняет что проблему составляет не сам парсинг php-файла, а `"the risks / stability / contention of self-modifying code"`.

По поводу парсинга, то здесь насколько понимаю особой разницы нету, взять ли

```
Config::$var или Config::$array[1]
```

с php-файла, или взять

```
json_decode($json)->{"property"}
```

с файла в формате json.

Но действительно ли хранение конфигурации в php-файле имеет большие риски в сравнении с другими форматами? Тем более когда в **.htaccess** дописать

```
RewriteRule config.php - [F]
```

И собственно опять же главный вопрос: в каком же формате лучше всего хранить конфигурацию?

Возможно здесь на самом деле два вопроса: в каком формате *файла* и в каком формате *данных*, поскольку я видел как один человек хранит конфигурацию как json в javascript-файле

Comment: Я в своём проекте храню в php файле. Причём файл содержит код `return [...];`. И соответственно использую его через `$config = include file.php;`

Answer (score 1):

Храню всегда в php в таком виде

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
...........
```

Плюсы: удобно хранить и использовать. Т.к. это константы, то нет возможностью случайно перезаписать значение.

Только одно но. Я всегда создаю каталог include рядом с каталогом public и все инклуды и конфиги храню там. Т.е. структура получается такая

```
..
|--include
|--public
   |--index.php
```

В итоге, когда пользователь запрашивает `http://mysite.com/` он получает файл `public\index.php` и до папки include злоумышленник может добраться только сломав FTP аккаунт

Comment: Т.е. `define()` лучше чем класс, внутри которого `public static $var` ?

Comment: Вроде как в define не получится сохранить массивы без танцев с бубнами, кроме того, если к сайту подключаются сторонние модули то они тоже увидят все эти константы.

Comment: Плагины должны их видеть. Но вот по поводу массива то да, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686842/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-define-%D0%BE%D1%82-const) пишут что `define()` понимает их лишь с РНР 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Symphony сейчас переводит свои конфиги с [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) на [php](/questions/tagged/php).

По той простой причине, что весь код на РНР. И в конфиге можно использовать переменные, константы, любые другие настройи РНР.
Плюс редактор автоматом цепляет настройки для автодополнения, без дополнительных плясок с бубном.

Ну и, про безопасность, РНР файл безопаснее для дешевого хостинга, где у тебя доступ только корневой папке веб-сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так делаю

```
;<?php /*
;Реквизиты для коннекта к LDAP
ldap_auth.user = userName
ldap_auth.pass = password
```

и разбираю его стандартным парсером ini-файлов

Тут надо понимать, что где-бы вы не хранили настройки(речь про файл), если web-сервер отдаст его злоумышленнику в исходном виде, то всё пропало. В этом плане `.php`, по сравнению с `.json`, `.ini` и т.д. имеет некоторые преимущества, поскольку сперва передается препроцессору PHP

Comment: Т.е. это лучше php-файла в плане безопасности?

Comment: Это наглядно и достаточно безопасно. Дополнил ответ